# How do I find out the longest run of a number?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This seemed like a trivial question to me, but I cannot get it done correctly. Part of my dataset looks like this

```
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

and contains two “runs” of 1 (not sure if that’s the correct word), one with a length 3, the other with a length of 5.

How can I use Google Docs or similar spreadsheet applications to find the longest of those runs?

Comment: Are all of these values in a single cell?  Also, is there a max number of values to be evaluated?

Comment: For future reference this question should have been asked at Super User - it is not programming related so does not belong at Stack Overflow

Answer (score 4):

In Excel you can use a single formula to get the maximum number of consecutive 1s, i.e.

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A100=1,ROW(A2:A100)),IF(A2:A100<>1,ROW(A2:A100))))
```

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

In Google Sheets you can use the same formula but wrap in arrayformula rather than use CSE, i.e.

```
=arrayformula(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A100=1,ROW(A2:A100)),IF(A2:A100<>1,ROW(A2:A100)))))
```

Assumes data in A2:A100 without blanks

Comment: +1 nice, do you know off-hand if you could extend the same formula to return what row (or specific cell) the max sequence ends in?

Comment: That's tricky, there's no simple way with the same sort of formula - much easier with your helper column, you can just use MATCH....

Comment: I found a complex way.....Assuming that first formula in C2 to find the max consecutive 1s then the formula in D2 will give the row of the last 1 in the first run of that size `=SMALL(IF(A2:A100<>1,ROW(A2:A100)),MATCH(C2,FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A100=1,ROW(A2:A100)),IF(A2:A100<>1,ROW(A2:A100))),0)-1)+C2`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: whuber's suggestion is just too simple for me to not update this response. One can just use a simple IF statement checking if the current row is equal to 1. If it is, it starts a counter (the prior row + 1), if it is not it starts the counter again at 0.

You just need to initialize the first row of B1 to 1 or 0. Using the dynamic updating of cell formulas once you have it written once it fills in the rest.

So you would start out;

```
A   B
1   1
1   =IF(A2=1, B1+1, 0)
1   
0   
0   
1   
1   
1   
1   
0   
0   
0
```

Then fill in;

```
A   B
1   1
1   =IF(A2=1, B1+1, 0)
1   =IF(A3=1, B2+1, 0)
0   =IF(A4=1, B3+1, 0)
0   =IF(A5=1, B4+1, 0)
1   =IF(A6=1, B5+1, 0)
1   =IF(A7=1, B6+1, 0)
1   =IF(A8=1, B7+1, 0)
1   =IF(A9=1, B8+1, 0)
0   =IF(A10=1, B9+1, 0)
0   =IF(A11=1, B10+1, 0)
0   =IF(A12=1, B11+1, 0)
```

And here the result in column B is;

```
A   B
1   1
1   2
1   3
0   0
0   0
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
0   0
0   0
0   0
```

Hopefully the logic is extendable to Google Docs.

Comment: +1 But simpler (and therefore more understandable) is `=IF(A3=1, B2+1, 0)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!

(I had originally posted the question to stats because I thought that statisticians need functions like these pretty often, and thought that (newer?) spreadsheet applications would offer this as a builtin.)

Comment: @MathiasMaul, that is true, but that doesn't make it on topic at the stats site. The [FAQ at the stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) talks about this. Don't worry though, confusion over where a question should be directed happens on a regular basis.