# calculate consecute streak in excel row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to calculate 2 values. Current Streak and Long Streak.

each record is on 1 row and contains a name and values

each of those columns has a value from 1 to 200.
Example:

```
John Doe 14 16 25 18 40 65 101 85 14 19 18 9 3
Jane Doe 24 22 18 5 8 22 17 17 15 2 1 5 22
Jim Doe 40 72 66 29 25 28
Jan Doe 27 82 22 17 18 9 6 7 9 13
```

For each row, I'm trying to find the "current" streak and "longest" streak.
The values have to be <= 24 to be counted. Data goes left to right.

```
John: Current 2; Long 5
Jane: Current 13; Long 13
Jim: Current 0; Long 0
Jan: Current 0; Long 8
```

What would be a formula to calculate the current and long in their own cell on that same row (would have to go before data)?

Comment: For the longest run, you can adapt barry's answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363049/in-a-spreadsheet-gdocs-or-similar-how-do-i-find-out-the-longest-run-of-a-numb

Comment: thanks @TimWilliams. As you can see, it was much different than barry's but he was able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For current run, assuming data in C2:Z2, try this array formula:

`=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,C2:Z2>24,0)-1,COUNT(C2:Z2))`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

For longest streak try this version based on the cell references used in your comment

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(P7:BB7<=24,COLUMN(P7:BB7)),IF(P7:BB7>24,COLUMN(P7:B‌​B7))))`

Again confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or to allow blanks in the range (which would end a streak) you can use this version

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(P7:BB7<>"",IF(P7:BB7<=24,COLUMN(P7:BB7))),IF((P7:BB7="")+(P7:BB7>24),COLUMN(P7:BB7))))`

Comment: Thanks @barry but it's not working. It keeps returning the total number of columns that have data regardless of the streak under 24.

Comment: @kylemac - that sounds like you haven't used `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` - if you do that correctly you get curly braces like { and } around the formula......or try this version which doesn't need `CSE` =IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C2:Z2>24,0),0)-1,COUNT(C2:Z2))`

Comment: Great @barry! nope, I'm not a big excel guy and trying to help a friend figure this out.  That worked great. Can you help me out with the long streak?

Comment: Did you try the method I suggested in Tim's link? For a row of data you need to use COLUMN function in place of ROW

Comment: yes. I tried: =arrayformula(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(P7:BB7=1,COLUMN(P7:BB7)),IF(P7:BB7<>1,COLUMN(P7:BB7))))) among other changes but I'm getting an 'Invalid Name Error'

Comment: arrayformula is only used in Google docs - I'll update my answer with a version for longest streak....

Comment: Thanks @barry, but I was able to get a value with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, BUT it's not really calculating the streak, it's just returning the number of times the less than 24 appears, not a count of a streak. (also how to exclude blank cells would help) I tried playing around using similar variations, but was unable to get anything. :-( I'm trying. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you might have blank "gaps" within the data? If you have blanks how should that work? Does a blank end the streak or do you want to continue the streak but not count the blank cells within it?