# calculate current consecutive streak ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a daily log with four different value types. Positive, Negative, Zero, or Blank.

I am interested in the consecutive Zeroes, where Positive and Negative values end the streak, and Blanks are ignored.

Each record is on 1 row and contains a name and values

Example:

```
Day  1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Fred 1 -2 0 _ 0 0 0 0  calculate current streak of 5
Jane 0 -5 _ 0 0 _ _ _  calculate current streak of 2
John 4 -6 3 0 0 0 3 0  calculate current streak of 1
Amie 2  0 0 0 0 0 0 -3 current streak 0
```

I can use COUNTIF to get the total zeroes, but not the streak

From this similar question, [calculate consecute streak in excel row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736286/calculate-consecute-streak-in-excel-row)

I've tried variations of `=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:I2<>0,0),0)-1,COUNT(B2:I2))`

I'm getting wonky results, and my supervisor wants me to be done with this already. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to keep everything one one line: `=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:I2<>0,0),0)-1,COUNT(B2:I2))`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, Thanks for noticing that, my formula does refer to one row. I mis-typed that formula when I simplified it from my spreadsheet. I adjusted the post to show the correct range. So the unchanged formula is still not giving me expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Formula in `K2`:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX((COLUMN(B2:I2)>LOOKUP(2,1/((B2:I2<>0)*(B2:I2<>"")),COLUMN(B2:I2)))*(B2:I2=0)*(B2:I2<>""),)),COUNTIF(B2:I2,0))
```

Drag down..

There probably is a neater way.

Comment: It works! Thank you, thank you! Maybe there is a "neater" way, but it's even *more neater that you took the time to help someone just because they asked! Thanks :)